# Why does Italy have night open bookstores?

Tags: italy, opening-hours

Saw something I'd never thought I'd ever see - night open bookstores. And they were crowded. Looking at the opening hours one bookstore close at 20:00 and then open again at 21:30 and stays open until 23:30.

The only other places in the town that are open are bars, restaurants and ice cream shops.

Why does Italy have night open bookstores?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel as defined in the [help]

Comment: @ReddHerring correct m.b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

August and September is often the time of the year that new books are launched

The bookstore probably just had a literary event.